# Interpretation of the SAS code

Tags: sas

Please, help me to interpret the SAS code (I am pretty new to sas and trying to rewrite the code from sas to stata).

```
PROC SQL;

 CREATE TABLE sample AS

  SELECT a.*, LOG(1 + b.pcyld) as u

  FROM sample AS a LEFT JOIN bondterm AS b

  ON a.compdate = b.compdate AND

   a.t_debt_round = b.roundmat;

QUIT;
```

Does it mean: from dataframe - "bondterm", generate r_debt = LOG(1 + b.pcyld). Then merge this database by compdate and t_debt_round (sample dataframe) = roundmat (bondterm). Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source tables are:

- sample
- bondterm

The data is left joined, so all records from SAMPLE are included, but if a record is in bondterm and not in sample it's not included.

- compdate (in both)
- debt_round from Sample joins to roundmat from
  bondterm

Fields selected:

- all from sample
- calculate new field u (log(1+ pcyld))

Output table:

- sample (same name as input which is usually not recommended)